# A canonical isomorphism from $V$ to $W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I am reading "Linear Algebra" by Ichiro Satake.

The notion "canonical" is very difficult for me.
I have questions about canonical isomorphisms.

The author wrote as follows:

> Taking the dual space, $V\mapsto V^*$, is a manipulation to produce a new vector space $V^*$ from the given one $V.$ What will then be obtained, if we repeat this process once again? By definition, $V^{**}$ is the vector space of all linear mappings of $V^*$ into $K.$ Now, for each $a\in V$, the correspondence $$V^*\ni f\mapsto f(a)\in K$$ is clearly a linear map from $V^*$ into $K.$ In fact, if we call this mapping $\phi_a$, then $\phi_a\in V^{**}$ and the mapping $V\ni a\mapsto\phi_a\in V^{**}$ gives an isomorphism of $V$ onto $V^{**}.$
> This isomorphism is "canonical" in the sense that it is defined in a natural, intrinsic manner, independently of the choice of basis. So, in what follows, we shall identify $V$ with $V^{**}$ by this isomorphism: $$V=V^{**},$$ (where $x\in V$ is identified with $\phi_x\in V^{**}$).
> For the iterated dual spaces, we have by $V=V^{**}$ $$V^{***}=(V^{*})^{**}=V^*,\\V^{****}=(V^{**})^{**}=V^{**}=V,\dots$$ which shows that no new spaces are obtained any more. In this sense, the operation $V\mapsto V^*$ is "reflexive."
> *Remark 1*. Some readers might think that $V$ and $V^*$, both being $n$-dimensional vector spaces, can also be identified with each other, say by the isomorphism defined by the correspondence of the bases $(e_i)\leftrightarrow (f_i).$ However, this correspondence depends essentially on the choice of the bases and hence is not canonical. Although $V$ and $V^*$ are isomorphic, there are many choices for the isomorphism, and in general there is no way to select a canonical one from among them.

Let $V,W$ be $n$-dimensional vector spaces.

- If we define an isomorphism from $V$ to $W$ by using bases, is the isomorphism always non-canonical?  (I cannot define "define an isomorphism from $V$ to $W$ by using bases".)
  Let $P(B_V, B_W)$ be a procedure which returns an isomorphism from $V$ to $W$, where $B_V$ is a basis of $V$ and $B_W$ is a basis of $W$ and $B_V$ and $B_W$ are inputs to $P$.
  Is there an example such that $P(B_V, B_W)=P(B_{V}^{'},B_{W}^{'})$ for any two bases $B_V$ and $B_{V}^{'}$ of $V$ and any two bases $B_W$ and $B_{W}^{'}$ of $W$?
- If we define an isomorphism from $V$ to $W$ without using bases, is the isomorphism always canonical?
- If we define two isomorphisms from $V$ to $W$ without using bases, are the two isomorphisms the same isomorphism?

Comment: It may be worth looking into category theory, which makes precise what the intuitive notion of "canonical" means.

Comment: @KentaS Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: Concerning the last bullet: No, I think that $a\mapsto-\phi_a$ gives a different canonical isomorphism from $V$ to $V^{**}$. (But I don't really know what "canonical" means either.)

Comment: @mr_e_man Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not an isomorphism is canonical depends (loosely speaking) on whether it is defined without having to make arbitrary choices. So you could think of "noncanonical" as rewriting

> this correspondence depends essentially on the choice of the bases and
> hence is not canonical

as

> this correspondence depends essentially on the choice of [some structure or feature] and
> hence is not canonical

The arbitrary choice is often a choice of basis but need not be.

So for the first bullet: if the  isomorphism actually depends on the bases then it's not canonical. The procedure $P$ you describe will be canonical if it behaves as you say. That can happen: the canonical isomorphism between a space and its second dual might be described that way (but that would be ugly and unnatural).

For the second and third bullets: perhaps. The answer depends essentially on whether you had to make any arbitrary choices.

If you go on to study more abstract algebra you will learn some category theory and encounter a more formal definition of "canonical".

Comment: Ethan Bolker, Thank you very much for your kind answer.